# Cant load MongoDb driver in php.ini using Apache in Xampp

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp

I am trying to learn PHP with mongodb backend, but I could not connect PHP to mongo because of the following error:

> fatal error Mongo class undefined

I am using Xampp and netbeans as IDE. I looked it up and got that the drivers are to be installed.

So I downloaded the drivers which is `php_mongo-1.4.x-5.5-vc11.dll`. I put it in the `.../php/ext/`folder and edit `php.ini` placing extention = `php_mongo.....dll`.

But still when I start my apache it says `php_mongo...dll` not found althought it is placed correctly. Also it says `libsasl.dll` not found, which when I looked up, it was in place.

I have mongodb installed and I have correct driver version, so why does it happen?

Comment: You might want to try `MongoClient` instead: `$m = new MongoClient();`

Comment: i tried that but it again says the same(fatal error). But the main problem here is despite placing the php_mongo.dll in ../php/ext folder my apache is saying that it cannot be found. also it says libsasl.dll not found although it is at its right place